# How to create 2 datalines in sas with different length

Tags: input, sas

I want to create a table like that:

```
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3 4
```

a has 3 values, b has 4.
How can I do it in SAS?
When I enter it like that it deletes the 4 at the end.

```
data my_data;
 input a b;
 datalines;
1 1
2 2
3 3
  4
```

I am very new to SAS thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use LIST MODE input, like in your example, then each variable needs to have a "word" on the line.  Use a period to indicate the missing values.

```
data my_data;
  input a b;
datalines;
1 1
2 2
3 3
. 4
;
```

Otherwise switch to COLUMN MODE input.

```
data my_data;
  input a 1-2 b 3-4 ;
datalines;
1 1
2 2
3 3
  4
;
```

Or FORMATTED MODE

```
data my_data;
  input a 2. b 2.;
datalines;
1 1
2 2
3 3
  4
;
```

Note that you can use the period to indicate a missing value even when the variable is character.  This is because the normal character informat will convert that single period into a blank value.

```
data my_data;
  input a $ b;
datalines;
1 1
2 2
3 3
. 4
;
```